# work with loops in bash

Tags: shell, for-loop

I have a "test" file where sometimes some data is put in 3-strings blocks.
It looks like:

```
v1 dad3
v2 100213
v3 <url1>
v1 mom5
v2 100255
v3 <url2>
..etc
```

I need a shell-script which will read this file and create a dir named by the value after v2 and create a text file named by the word after v1. Also it would be great if it can wget file on the url after v3.

Eg here 1st dir should be named '100213' with text file 'dad3' and file from 'url1'.
2nd should be '100255' with text file 'mom5' and file from 'url2'.
I began to write a script, however there are some difficulties:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR1=/home/user/aaa
for i in $(grep var2 $DIR1/test|awk '{print $2}');
do mkdir $i;
cd $i;
   for name in $(grep var1 $DIR1/test|awk '{print $2}'); do
   if [ -f "$DIR1/$i/$name" ];
    then echo have;
    else
   touch $name;
   fi
   done;
   cd $DIR1;
done
```

Obviously the second "for name" cycle works not as expected: it creates text files of all "v1" values in all new directories. Can we use only one cycle here or make 2nd one pause while 1st process next block (looks for the next v2 value and creates new directory)?

Comment: A better title for the question would be helpful. I doubt very much that anyone with a similar issue will find this by searching for "work with cycle".

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run `grep`, it rereads the file from the start -- so you can't use it to do anything where your place in the file matters.

The description of your desired behavior isn't very clear. However, the code below should give you an idea of how to operate in a single pass (thus, no need for nested loops -- "cycles" are the word you're using?) at all.

```
while read -r var val; do
  case $var in
    v1)
      v1="$val"
      ;;
    v2)
      v2="$val"
      mkdir -p "$v2"
      ;;
    v3)
      v3="$val"
      if [[ $v2 && $v1 ]]; then
        curl -- "$v3" >"$v2/$v1.txt"
        v1=
        v2=
      else
        echo "ERROR: Saw v3 without preceding v2 and v1; ignoring" >&2
      fi
      ;;
  esac
done <test
```

See also [entry #1 from the wooledge.org BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: yes, perhaps loops is the better word for this. How can I read my test file? Shall I use 'cat' before? Using awk '{print $2}' construction is also important because v1,v2,v3 are only markers and for naming I need to use only second word, e.g. 'dad3'.

Comment: Look at how my example works -- yes, it *does* work, and it doesn't have or need a `cat`. The `<test` at the end is how it reads the file. I included a link to BashFAQ #1 if you want to understand _how_ it works.